# Chat box in the right panel shows "Could not access chat."

Tags: bug, status-completed

Actual screenshot:

[image]

Comment: I have the same problem.

Comment: This issue has also been raised on meta.stackoverflow about the Apple.SE site.

Comment: Ok, it looks like it is quite common among SE2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a DNS error that will correct itself in 24 hours.